# need script to export file to remote server

Tags: ruby

AIX 5.3
DB 10.2.0.4

My requirement is to create a script that does export a big table from source to remote destination server and on remote destination database server to create another script that import that export table.
In export script I need to add to purge exported data and it schedule on weekly basis.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot to this question.  I would recommend you break it down and investigate how to accomplish each piece.  For example:

- Copy files between computers:  see `scp`
- Execute tasks on remote server: see `ssh`
- Schedule on weekly basis:  see `cron`

Your question may be better served on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), as well.

Comment: It is not like that send me in proper steps in term of oracle pl/sql code with shell scripting

Comment: Sorry Ahmad, you can't expect StackOverflow users to do everything for you.  I believe I've pointed you in the right direction with the three tools I mentioned (`scp`, `ssh`, and `cron`).  Each has a manual page (run `man scp`, for example) that you can refer to.  If you run into a specific problem or question, I'm sure people will be happy to help.